# VIF Values for Multicollinearity

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I have a cross-sectional dataset which I obtained from panel data. All the variables are on macroeconomics with n=75. I want to check my variables for multicollinearity using VIF. I got the following results :

mean VIF: 1.62 
mean VIF: 1.55

I do not know what values to use in order to compare VIF. My professor's lecture notes say that if mean VIF>1 then it is evidence for multicollinearity. However, I searched for more information on this issue and I understood that there no appropriate value but it depends of the kind of the research.

How do I know which level is appropriate for my research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think that using condition indexes and proportion of variance explained is a much better way to diagnose approximate collinearity.  That's what [my dissertation](http://fordham.bepress.com/dissertations/AAI9926897/) showed.  VIFs don't give as much information and are possibly not as good at the diagnose of how much collinearity is enough to cause problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read a little bit for condition indexes and I am going to apply it. However, probably there is problem with downloading the "collin" command. I can't download it and I saw that also other users had the same problem.